# Populate column with string used for matching using data.tables

Tags: r, data.table

Here I am creating the two data.tables

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)

mydt <- data.table(summary=c("Denial of Service vulnerability in BIND 8 Releases",
                          "Denial of Service vulnerabilities in BIND 4.9 and BIND 8",
                          "Buffer overflow in NFS mountd gives root access",
                          "Buffer overflow in statd allows root privileges.",
                          "Cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerability in Open-Xchange",
                          "SQL injection vulnerability in mod_accounting.c in the"),
                    wascname=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"SQL Injection"))

 wasc <- data.table(wascname=c("Abuse of Functionality",
                              "Cross-Site Scripting",
                              "Buffer Overflow",
                              "Denial of Service",
                              "SQL Injection"))
```

Output for mydt

[image]

Here solution I am using to populate column using the string used for matching.

```
mydt$wascname <-
   sapply(1:nrow(mydt), function(x)
     ifelse(
       is.na(mydt$wascname[x]),
       wasc$wascname[str_detect(mydt$summary[x],
                                     regex(wasc$wascname, ignore_case = TRUE))],
       mydt$wascname[x]
     ))
```

Output

[image]

I would like to achieve the same result using data.table form `DT[i, j, by]`. I tried different solution, I could not get to work using `DT` form.

I thought more on this while sleeping and rewrote a work around to achieve the `DT[i, j, by]` form. Please see work around below which gives me desired output:

```
 mydt[ , wascname:= sapply(1:nrow(mydt),function(x)
   ifelse(is.na(wascname[x]),
          wasc$wascname[str_detect(summary[x],
                                   regex(wasc$wascname, ignore_case = TRUE))],
          wascname[x]))]
```

Comment: u can try with normal `if else` statement using `grepl`

Comment: Sorry `grepl` will not work because you have to convert column to single pattern string, which results in loosing string used in matching

Comment: `grepl` will work with this `wasc[ , .(summary = mydt$summary[grepl(wascname, mydt$summary, ignore.case = T)]),  by = wascname]` but I feel unhappy with this answer.

Comment: There are a few feature requests for string matching between tables. Fwiw, I linked your Q on this one: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/636

Comment: @utubun your solution is using the vector `wasc` to create a new data.table. I want that to remain as is(vector) because I keep adding to it for example when there are new `WASC names`. `mydt$summary` column is used for searching if a string from `wasc$wascname` vector exist in it. If it does populate `mydt$wascname` with value from `wasc$wascname`. I have added a work around i thought of after waking up. Is there a better way of doing it? @Frank thanks for submitting a question on github. Can you explain your proposed solution what it is doing?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)

df2<- mydt %>%
  mutate(match = str_extract(tolower(mydt$summary), str_c(tolower(wasc), collapse = "|")))
```

this will give your desired output.

stringr with tidyverse will work in this case.

**make sure wasc is saved as a list**